# Frontend Authentication with GraphQl on different domain

Tags: authentication, headless

I want to build a headless craft-cms site. Frontend is on mydomain.com, backend on login.mydomain.com

However, i want users to login in the frontend and create a session there. Only logged in users can then see some sites or data on the website.

How would i achieve this authentication over different domains?